# understanding ruby inject

Tags: ruby, inject

I'm confused about this codethat didn't work for me.

```
tab=Array.new
tab<<"1,2,3"
tab<<"4"
tab<<"5,6"
x=tab.inject([]){|t,elt|

  if elt.include?(',')
    s=elt.split(',')
    s.each{|y| t<<y}
  else
    t<<elt
  end
 }
STDOUT.puts x
```

============= outpout:5 6
but if i change the code,

```
tab=Array.new
tab<<"1,2,3"
tab<<"4"
tab<<"5,6"
x=tab.inject([]){|t,elt|

  if elt.include?(',')
    s=elt.split(',')
    s.each{|y| t<<y}
  else
    t<<elt
  end
   t.each{|tt| tt} #i add this line

}
STDOUT.puts x
```

======output: 1 2 3 4 5 6
does anyone has an explanation?
thx

Comment: This whole thing could be written `tab.join(",").split(",")`

Comment: @MarkThomas +1 you.. for your idea. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `#inject` block, you passed last entry as `"5,6"`. Now inside the `if` block, you splitted it to an array. Then you called the method `#each` on `[5,6]`. Now `#each` method returns the receiver on which you called it.

But in the second case, you called `t.each` at the last of each iteration of the `inject` block. So on the final pass `t` is a complete array `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. Now as I said, `Array#each` returns the receiver, so you got the full `t` back , that `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

I would write your code as :

```
ary = ["1,2,3","4","5,6"]
ary.flat_map { |str| str.include?(",") ? str.split(',') : str }
# => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
```

If you want to use `#inject` do :

```
ary = ["1,2,3","4","5,6"]
ary.inject([]) { |a,str| a.concat(str.split(',')) }
# => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `inject`, the return value from each block is passed to the subsequent block. Your first example, the return value is the value of `s.each{|y| t<<y}`; the final iteration will return `[5, 6]`. Your second example indirectly returns `t`; `t.each { }` returns `t` so that additional methods can be chained to it.

You need to return the collection you're building up at the end of each block:

```
x=tab.inject([]){|t,elt|

  if elt.include?(',')
    s=elt.split(',')
    s.each{|y| t << y}
  else
    t<<elt
  end

  t

}
```

You can make this significantly smaller however; just add the new element(s) to the existing elements, and return the result:

```
tab.inject([]) { |t, elt|
  t + elt.include?(',') ? elt.split(',') : Array[elt]
}
```